# Facebook login in facebook bots

Tags: bots, facebook-login, facebook-messenger

Can I add a facebook login button to a facebook messenger conversation via facebook bot or any other bot?

Comment: I'm confused why you would want this. If someone is in a Messenger conversation they are already logged in. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want to go this but one reason might be to get more user permissions (e.g. user_friends). Currently Messenger doesn't allow you to ask for these types of user permissions, you can only do this with a Facebook Login.

Messenger doesn't have a Facebook Login button in the API so the only way I've seen to do this is to create your own html and Javascript Facebook Login page using the [Javascript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/) and the [Messenger Extensions SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webview/extensions/). Basically all you need to do is add both of these SDKs in the Javascript and create an html button for the user to press on to trigger the login.

You can send a link to this login page via your bot in a url button. Make sure you enable Messenger Extensions on that button. When the user clicks on the button a webview will open with the Facebook login page you've created.

When someone presses on the Login button it should return both the app-scoped-id (and an access token) as well as the page-scoped-id (Messenger id). Now you should be able to link each bot user with an app-scoped-id and an access token.